# Airmon-ng doesn't show any thing in Microsoft's versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, windows-10, aircrack-ng, microsoft

I have two wireless cards, one internal and one external and I want to run Airodump-ng in Microsoft's versions of Ubuntu after installing it with this [method](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)

My wireless cards:

1- Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160
2- Tp-link Tl-wn722n Atheros Ar9271

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The version of Ubuntu you are running on top of Windows is containerized, and does not generally have direct access to the hardware. The network connection is bridged to the host. This means certain tools, such as *airmon-ng* may not work as expected.

Comment: so is there any way to make it work on it ?

Comment: No. You could run Ubuntu in a VM instead, and use PCI pass through to pass control of your WiFi chip to the VM. This would of course mean you couldn't control it from Windows any longer. You could instead add a secondary WiFi adapter via USB and pass it through to the VM, instead of the primary WiFi chip.

Comment: Ok but i couldn't use my internal  in the vm with aircrack-ng but the usb one worked. But i want to use tge both of them and still use the windows os at the same time.  Is there a way?  Please 